# AppSink methods missing: AttributeError: 'GstAppSink' object has no attribute 'is_eos'

Tags: python, gstreamer, pygobject

I'm trying to use the AppSink sink to read samples from it but none of the AppSink methods seem to exist on the object.

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst
Gst.init()

pipe = Gst.parse_launch("audiotestsrc ! opusenc ! appsink name=sink")
sink = pipe.get_by_name("sink")

while not sink.is_eos():
    pass
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 9, in <module>
    while not sink.is_eos():
AttributeError: 'GstAppSink' object has no attribute 'is_eos'
```

gstreamer version:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.14.1
GStreamer 1.14.1
https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer1.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `appsink` interface is in a different library than the base GStreamer one. You will need to import `GstApp` as well:

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
gi.require_version("GstApp", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst, GstApp

Gst.init(None)

pipe = Gst.parse_launch("audiotestsrc ! opusenc ! appsink name=sink")
sink = pipe.get_by_name("sink")

while not sink.is_eos():
    pass
```

Comment: So you have to import `GstApp` even if it's an unused import??

Comment: Unused? `is_eos()` is part of the `AppSink` interface - which is being used. Remove the use of `is_eos()` and you could skip the import.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I can't award the bounty just yet, but I will when the timeout passes.